# Trying to figure out transforming on OGL ES 2.0 for Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am still learning the basics of OpenGL, but I am having trouble doing transformations.

I have a quad I want to move around, and apply a projection matrix onto. Is their a certain order the matrices must be multiplied? Does it matter if a matrix is on the left or right side of a multiplication (like with a matrix and a vector) with two matrices?

Doing identity matrix -> transformation matrix works, however if I try to multiply that by a projection matrix, the quad disappears.

Comment: have you found an answer yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while doing transformations the order of transformations sure does effect the final rendering. For example.. if you try to scale an object and do translate transformation on it the final rendering will be different when you reverese the same order.

It worked for you when you did the transformation with an Identity matrix 'coz when you do any Transformation using an Identity there will not be any change.

While do Transformation the order of Matrices is also important, change the order the final rendering changes.

If it helps please go through "OpenGL Superbible 5th editio". This will give you a fair knowledge on how transformation happen.